# Is it possible to setup a json grab using curl, to grab using current date and changing out dates for next 5 days in script?

Tags: json, curl

I'm a bit of a beginner.  I have a curl script to grab a json that works just fine. Towards the end of the script are date parameters.

`--data-raw '{"filterParam":{"day":11,"time":17,"minute":30,"month":2,"year":2021}}`

Here's what I'm hoping to achieve.  Is it possible to setup to where the "day", "month" and "year" use the day I'm running, so that its automated?

Also, is it possible to substitute the dates for the next 5 days.  In other words, a json is pulled with today's date.  Then it grabs a json with tomorrows date (using 1 day from current day) and so on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether you're using a shell or not, but if so, you can use [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) to format the JSON. Assuming Unix Bash:

```
xidel -se '
  let $a:=current-dateTime() return {
    "filterParam":{
      "day":day-from-dateTime($a),
      "time":17,
      "minute":30,
      "month":month-from-dateTime($a),
      "year":year-from-dateTime($a)
    }
  }
'
{
  "filterParam": {
    "day": 21,
    "time": 17,
    "minute": 30,
    "month": 2,
    "year": 2021
  }
}
```

For use with `curl` use `serialize()` to turn the JSON into a string:

```
xidel -se '
  let $a:=current-dateTime() return
  serialize(
    {
      "filterParam":{
        "day":day-from-dateTime($a),
        "time":17,
        "minute":30,
        "month":month-from-dateTime($a),
        "year":year-from-dateTime($a)
      }
    },
    {"method":"json"}
  )
'
{"filterParam":{"day":21,"time":17,"minute":30,"month":2,"year":2021}}
```

Simply do `day-from-dateTime($a) + 1` to have it return `{"day":22,[...]}`

There's a pretty good chance by the way that what you want to do with `curl` `xidel` can do too.